# Meteor/ng2: Where to process a variable that requires two subscription to be resolved

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-directives

Assume I have

```
this.subscribe('a', () => {this.allA = A.find();});
this.subscribe('b', () => {this.allB= B.find();});
```

And a variable that is something like

```
let x = *take the first A, do some calculation to get the B linked, return B*
```

**Where such logic be put to be sure this is only processed when subscriptions 'a' and 'b' are resolved ?**

Might be using zones but I am not 100% what could be the best way to do it in a @Component.

PS: avoid do-a-serverside-method :D

Regards

Comment: iron:router's waitOn provides such logic to wait for multiple subscription, I am not using iron router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems for now to be to wrap it in a autorun (MeteorComponent for instance)

```
this.autorun(()=>{
    let s1 = this.subscribe('a', () => {this.allA = A.find();});
    let s2 = this.subscribe('b', () => {this.allB= B.find();});

    if(s1.ready() && s2.ready()) 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using callbacks in your subscriptions, return subscription handles and then check their `ready()` state:

```
const subA = this.subscribe('a');
const subB = this.subscribe('b');
const that = this;

Tracker.autorun(()=>{
  if ( subA.ready() ) that.allA = A.find();
  if ( subB.ready() ) that.allB = B.find();
  if ( subA.ready() && subB.ready() ) {
    let x = ... //compute x
  }
});
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but in your example, none of the lines are blocking. So when the .ready() are reached, the result is most likely false (called directly after the subscribe). Would you put it in a setTimeout to run it as long as its not ready ?

Comment: Wrapping it in an autorun as you've done in your answer would allow the computations to be reactive.